# angular Spring Boot File Upload Example

Tags: angular, typescript, spring-boot, angular-file-upload, multipartfile

I want to Upload File To Spring boot backend , How should I send Formdata as requestparam in postrequest, i tried following code

### angular service class code

```
let headers=new HttpHeaders({
               'Content-Type="multipart/form-data'
                })
                const formData:FormData=new FormData();
                formdata.apend('file',file);
                 return this.http.post(uploaadfile,{params:{
                 file:formData,
                  contracttemplateid:28
                  }},options);
```

### spring boot controller code

```
@postmapping
uploadfile(@requestparam("file") MultipartFile 
file,@requestparam("contracttemplateid") long id)
{
}
```

Comment: read -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Uploadfile(formData: FormData, FileName: string){    
   return this.http.post('URL',formData,{'params': {filename : FileName}});
  }

let fd = new FormData();
let FileName = "FileName";

fd.append(SeletedFile, FileName)

Uploadfile(fd,FileName);
```

Comment: removed http options and used proxy config.json to avoid cors issue  that worked for me...im accepting the answer